# Self referencing a class

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a class that'll model a conversation.

```cs
[System.Serializable]
public class Choice
{
    // Just a sentence to show what kind of choice player is making
    public string choiceLine;

    // The whole answer that will be given
    public Sentence choiceDetailed;

    // The Answer/Response NPC will give to our Choice
    public Sentence npcAnswer;

    // If last answer of the NPC is given, go back to the main page
    private bool isLastAnswer;


    public Choice[] choices;
}
```

But I think there's a problem with the self referencing class, is there a better way to do this? I want to nest `Choice`s inside one `Choice` object.

Is this recursion model would be a problem?

Comment: Just a note, you have a class called `Choice` with member names that start with `choice`. Is it really necessary to do that? With respect to your original question, why not make another class that has the choices and keep the Choice as something that models the info in each one. The way you have it is probably not the way to go.

Comment: Also we don't have enough information on what you are planning to do with this to give you a suggested approach. Which in either case, this feels really opinion based.

Comment: What problem do you think there is with this class? If your conversations form a tree (they typically do), then a recursive representation like this is a suitable way of modelling it.

Comment: _"I think there's a problem with the self referencing class"_ -- why? what problem do you think there is? Without an actual problem statement, there is no problem, and so no suitable question for Stack Overflow. At best, we can only say "it's legal code", which the compiler already tells you, as does the duplicate question.

Comment: Side note: be careful with `serializable` and ["looped NPC"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f1k2ivJoRpc) (it is perfectly legal to have loop in choices)

Answer (score 1):

Given what you intend to use it for it is fine. Think of it like a linked list, but instead of only one possible `next` you have multiple options (if I understood it's usage correctly). Is it the most appropriate choice? That would require more information about your requirements. Also that probably would become opinion-based.

I would update the naming convention so it's clear what each field does. If it's doing too many things you might want to try splitting it into more than one field, if possible. Generally you shouldn't have to rely on comments to explain what is intended by each field as the name should make it clear. That doesn't mean you should never use comments, just use it sparingly and wisely.

For example, if your `choices` is the next set of choices if this particular choice is selected then you might want to prepend it with `next`.